# onNavigationItemSelected on Android Studio 3.5

Tags: android

I am using android studio 3.5. I'm trying to implement `onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menu)` but this give me this error: `Method '(onNavigationItemSelected.android.View.MenuItem)' is never used.`

Comment: Method is never used is a warning, not an error and once you implement and start using the method, the warning will go away

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the proper annotation (@Override) there?